# How to integrate Authorize.Net in Android application ?

Tags: android, authorize.net

I want to integrate my app with Authorize.Net. I have followed the Steps given in [tutorial](https://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android).

Some how I have managed to create an Library project anet_android_sdk. Now my library project  anet_android_sdk showing no error. But when I created a new project as in step 3. I am getting error.

```
import net.authorize.android.AuthNet;
import net.authorize.android.AuthNetActivityBase;
import net.authorize.android.SimpleActivity;
import net.authorize.android.button.AuthNetButton;
```

This import statement are not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Finally some how I managed to solve it.Actual problem was with the creating a anet_android_sdk library project and adding it to my project.

Comment: can you explain me how to create anet_android_sdk? i m working on same.

Comment: yes I checked that code. can you provide me any sample application with sdk?

Comment: This post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24485899/issues-in-integrating-authorize-net-apis-for-android.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have problem with adding jar file,Go to your project 
properties -> java Build Path -> order and Export and select jar file in checkbox then clean project ..
May be this can help you