# Issues in Integrating Authorize.net API's for android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, authorize.net

I want to integrate my app with Authorize.Net. I have followed the Steps given in tutorial http://developer.authorize.net/integration/fifteenminutes/android/.

my library project anet_android_sdk showing no error. But when I created a new project as in step 3. I am getting error.

`import net.authorize.android.AuthNet;
import net.authorize.android.AuthNetActivityBase;
import net.authorize.android.SimpleActivity;
import net.authorize.android.button.AuthNetButton;`

Comment: I faced the same problem integrating authorize.net but I had overcomed it.I cant exactly remember from where I got the code.The sdk seems to be somewhat incomplete.You can try this: http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/

Comment: I not getting from specified url. Can you help me out.

Comment: Search with  net.authorize.android in google.You will get your necessary classes in github

Comment: Hi sir any another way, because I have made all kind of search I think nothing find about that. Please help if you can .

Comment: Same problem here. Why don't they include this in jar? googling just brings me back here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the **anet_android_sdk** folder you will find the **src** folder and within that you will find some packages and classes.Just take the necessary packages and classes like
net.authorize.android.aim,net.authorize.android.arb,net.authorize.android.button,net.authorize.android.cim,net.authorize.android.notification etc. in your project.Maintain them within different packages as in the src folder.

The full source code can be found here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5tCy5V7jKsdOEdPS3c1VTc2MTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes sir, your right but I cant find any folder named anet_android_sdk, I have downloaded the sdk folder form this link https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-mpos-android in this link I cant saw folder structure like u had said.

Comment: I guess you have downloaded the sdk for android?!?

Comment: Yeah I am looking for android integration. do you have sample for android?

Comment: okk...I guess they have updated.I took a look at the sdk and saw that it still contains src folder.Within that folder you can find necessary packages that will resolve the compilation issues.

Comment: The 4 lines which I have mentioned above i.e                  `import net.authorize.android.AuthNet;
import net.authorize.android.AuthNetActivityBase;
import net.authorize.android.SimpleActivity;
import net.authorize.android.button.AuthNetButton;`    this files are not there in SRC folder.

Comment: plz send on this id rmergu33@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56535/discussion-between-rajeshmergu-and-kgandroid).

Comment: did able to you fix this ?

Comment: @kgandroid I have downloaded the above code it is helpful for me . But I have one question as a user point of view we will show the screen which contain Card Number , Expiration Date ,Card Code , First Name , Last Name , City , State , Country , ZipCode and some more edittext are there. How can we achieve this? Plzz Help